# Point check against lat and lng value if statement not working

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to see if a lat and long that is entered corresponds with one of two types of polygons either one with a key of Live and one with a key of Soon, however I cant seem to get the if statement right.

So if a lat + long point is in a polygon key Live the result should be, Location is found and is live. If a lat + long point is in a polygon key Soon the result should be, Location is found and is coming soon. If the lat + long does not reside in a polygon the result should be, Location is not found. However this last else statement does not work.

Here is a codepen link [Codepen](http://codepen.io/simonfricker/pen/eJMepp)

**Dependencies**

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/geocomplete/1.6.5/jquery.geocomplete.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="location_container"class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
    <p>w11 2ed - soon</p>
    <p>w10 5nr - live</p>
    <p>sw19 5aw - not live and not coming soon</p>

        <input id="location" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
        <div id="result"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="map_div"></div>
```

**Jquery**

```
function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5072, -0.1275),
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });

    initGeocompleteControl(map, function (result) {
  map.data.forEach(function (f) {

      if (f.getProperty("key") == "live") {

          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          calcBounds(f.getGeometry(), bounds);

          if (bounds.contains(result.geometry.location)) {
              $( "#result" ).empty();
              $("#result").html('Location is found and is live');
              console.log('Location is found and is live')
          }

      }
      else if
            (f.getProperty("key") == "soon") {

                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                calcBounds(f.getGeometry(), bounds);

                if (bounds.contains(result.geometry.location)) {
                    $( "#result" ).empty();
                    $("#result").html('Location is found and is coming soon');
                    console.log('Location is found and is coming soon')
                }

            }
            else {
                  $( "#result" ).empty();
                  $("#result").html('Location is not found');
                  console.log('Location is not found')
              }


       });
       });

    map.data.loadGeoJson('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/SimonFricker/39540c7fb6e332456640/raw/7a9dee5b9ab7f9a04082c65f2378928b8c027dcd/polygon.json');

}

function initGeocompleteControl(map, complete) {
    var option = {
        //types: ['(cities)']
         country: 'GB'
    };
    $("#location").geocomplete(option).bind("geocode:result", function (event, result) {
        complete(result);
    });
}


function calcBounds(geometry, bounds) {
    if (geometry instanceof google.maps.LatLng) {
        bounds.extend(geometry);
    }
    else if (geometry instanceof google.maps.Data.Point) {
        bounds.extend(geometry.get());
    }
    else {
        geometry.getArray().forEach(function (g) {
            calcBounds(g, bounds);
        });
    }
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: How do you get a point in the polygons? (or anywhere for that matter)

Comment: Please see the codepen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your else statement will only run for polygons.  If the point is outside of any polygon, it will never be executed.  You need to add a flag to detect when you have found the point inside a polygon, if you have processed all the polygons and not found the point inside one of them, then execute the "not found" code.

One option:

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zd728suj/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var marker;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5072, -0.1275),
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });

  initGeocompleteControl(map, function(result) {
    if (!marker || !marker.setPosition) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: result.geometry.location,
        map: map
      });
    } else {
      marker.setPosition(result.geometry.location);
    }
    var inPolygon = false;
    map.data.forEach(function(f) {

      if (f.getProperty("key") == "live") {

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        calcBounds(f.getGeometry(), bounds);

        if (bounds.contains(result.geometry.location)) {
          $("#result").empty();
          $("#result").html('Location is found and is live');
          console.log('Location is found and is live');
          inPolygon = true;
        }

      } else if (f.getProperty("key") == "soon") {

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        calcBounds(f.getGeometry(), bounds);

        if (bounds.contains(result.geometry.location)) {
          $("#result").empty();
          $("#result").html('Location is found and is coming soon');
          console.log('Location is found and is coming soon');
          inPolygon = true;
        }

      }
    });
    if (!inPolygon) {
      $("#result").empty();
      $("#result").html('Location is not found');
      console.log('Location is not found')
    }
  });

  map.data.loadGeoJson('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/SimonFricker/39540c7fb6e332456640/raw/7a9dee5b9ab7f9a04082c65f2378928b8c027dcd/polygon.json');

}

function initGeocompleteControl(map, complete) {
  var option = {
    //types: ['(cities)']
    country: 'GB'
  };
  $("#location").geocomplete(option).bind("geocode:result", function(event, result) {
    complete(result);
  });
}


function calcBounds(geometry, bounds) {
  if (geometry instanceof google.maps.LatLng) {
    bounds.extend(geometry);
  } else if (geometry instanceof google.maps.Data.Point) {
    bounds.extend(geometry.get());
  } else {
    geometry.getArray().forEach(function(g) {
      calcBounds(g, bounds);
    });
  }
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/geocomplete/1.6.5/jquery.geocomplete.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places"></script>
<div id="location_container" class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <p>w11 2ed - soon</p>
    <p>w10 5nr - live</p>
    <p>sw19 5aw - not live and not coming soon</p>

    <input id="location" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
    <div id="result"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="map_div"></div>
```